# Cut cross-break duct?

Tags: ducts

I bought a piece of rectangular duct from my local home supply store but it is slightly larger than what I need.  The ducts they sell are cross-broken instead of beaded.  Is it ok to cut down a duct that is already cross-broken?  If so should I try to cut an equal amount of each end so the cross-break is still in the middle of the duct?

Comment: yes you can cut the duct

Comment: @d.george, see my edit: Do I need to worry about cutting an equal amount off each end so the cross break is still centered?

Comment: No ------- the cross break is to attempt to stop the duct from making noise when the fan motor starts and starts.  The cross break does not have to be centered. You can cut either end or both ends; your choice.